# How to trigger a function on an element only when it has two specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have this bit of code to delay image loading by changing all 'img data-src' to 'img src'.

```
function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
```

At the moment it triggers when the page loads. What I want is for it to trigger only when an element has both classes .lazy and .show

The elements all look like this:

```
<li class="lazy hidden baratheon packcore" data-filtertext="01048"><a><div><img data-src="img/01048.jpg" class="cardimg"></div></a></li>
```

.hidden is assigned display:none, .show has display:block, and there are various clicks which will .addClass 'show' and .removeClass 'hidden'.

I've played around with various combinations of

```
$( 'lazy, .show' ) (function () {
```

but I clearly understand even less than I thought I did and can't get it to work.

How do I trigger a function when an element exists with two specific classes - and apply the function only to those elements?

And is it better to have this as a separate script always looking for those two classes, or to include it in the .addclass 'show' scripts so it automatically runs when .show is added?

edit: corrected the li code to show data-src instead of just src

Comment: Try `.lazy.show` (no space between)

Comment: @marekful I tried: `$( '.lazy.show' ) (function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } });
window.onload = init;`  with no luck. (Tried it with and without the window.onload line as I think I shouldn't use that but am not 100% sure). My code still does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery each() function to iterate through your .lazy.show listitems. Then for each one, find the child image and set src to value in data-src:

```
  $(".lazy.show").each(function(idx){    
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    var src = $img.data("src");
    $img.prop("src", src);
  });
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/RLzrJx)**

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! :) and a clear explanation of why it works too!  I attached this to the click events which were adding .show, and I added a .removeClass 'lazy' line after so that it only triggers once for each image. Thankyou @ezanker :)

Answer (score 1):

*Checking the classes..*

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",f);
function f(){
var i = document.body.childNodes;
for(var k=0;k < i.length; k++){
var e = i[k];
if(typeof e.className === 'undefined') continue;
if((e.className.indexOf("a") > -1) && (e.className.indexOf("b") > -1)) {
e.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="a" placeholder="Only a class">
<input type="text" class="a b" placeholder="a class and b class">
</body>
</html>
```